# How to create PrivateKey from a password protected private key file?

Tags: java, private-key

I have a password protected private key file(I have the passowrd).

I need to put it in java.security.PrivateKey format. Can anyone tell me what is the most secure way to do it?

Comment: What file format is the key in? Only certain file formats can be read by Java.

Comment: The key is created using `openssl` and it is RSA private key, 1024 bit long modulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key (with the certificates) is stored in PKCS#12 you can use the [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) from Java.

Else bouncy castle could help you (I've no experience with bouncy castle).

Comment: An example of `keystore` will be very helpful

Comment: Look at the documentation link I've provided. There is an example in the documentation.